# Magento 1.9 file structure - in particular public_html

Tags: magento-1.9

This should be a quick yes/no reply.

I am having difficulty in getting any theme to work, and think this may be due to file structure. I have a public_html folder that contains the files for base, rwd, default templates. Yet the themes I install affect only the app, js and skin folders. When I have investigated Magento file structure, I can see no reference to a public_html folder, so am wondering if this should be there?

Comment: Basically public_html folder point to your domain name

Comment: magento setup should be in that

Comment: You can check magento file structure here https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/structure.htm

Answer (score 1):

You will find any you need to know about theming in Magento in the official documentation: http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf